# AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize - trying to inject JAR file

Tags: java, java-8, instrumentation, agent, adoptopenjdk

*All other questions on the subject did not solve my problem.*

Injector:

```
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
vm.loadAgent(new File("inject.jar").getAbsolutePath());
vm.detach();
```

inject.jar has the correct manifest and everything. Inject code:

```
public static void agentmain(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("test");
    // also tried: writing a file to an absolute location,
    // and adding Instrument to the signature above
}
```

I get the error mentioned in the title when I run the injector.

inject.jar manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Agent-Class: Main
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was my agentmain function, which had `String[]` instead of `String` as the first argument.